# Trying to use Geogebra code in TexStudio

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, geogebra

I have drawn a figure (a square inside a quarter circle). When I export it in tikz and paste that in my texstudio, the quarter circle output is not shown, even though the other figure shows up fine:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-19.210333466054728,
xmax=20.87167851254458,
ymin=-14.541787054587674,
ymax=10.522690092979717,
xtick={-18,-16,...,20},
ytick={-14,-12,...,10},]
\clip(-19.210333466054728,-14.541787054587674) rectangle (20.87167851254458,10.522690092979717);
\draw [shift={(-10,4)},line width=2pt]  plot[domain=0:1.5707963267948966,variable=\t]({1*6*cos(\t r)+0*6*sin(\t r)},{0*6*cos(\t r)+1*6*sin(\t r)});
\draw [line width=2pt] (-10,10)-- (-10,4);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-10,4)-- (-4,4);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-10,6.95338163842107)-- (-7.471274548839627,4);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-7.471274548839627,4)-- (-4.438909754691155,6.252615209824085);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-10,6.95338163842107)-- (-6.967268362401102,9.177116843795076);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-6.967268362401102,9.177116843795076)-- (-4.438909754691155,6.252615209824085);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-10,4)-- (-4.438909754691155,6.252615209824085);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-4.438909754691155,6.252615209824085)-- (-4.430752531993374,4);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-10,6.95338163842107)-- (-4.438909754691155,6.252615209824085);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=ududff] (-10,4) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (-9.797934874774151,4.560623007772495) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=ududff] (-4,4) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (-3.796208806738503,4.560623007772495) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=ududff] (-10,10) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (-9.797934874774151,10.403713144494429) node {$C$};
\draw[color=black] (-5.514764729303777,8.711596543814773) node {$c$};
\draw[color=black] (-10.326721312486542,7.3103124838769356) node {$f$};
\draw[color=black] (-6.916048789241616,3.899639960632005) node {$g$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-10,6.95338163842107) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-9.797934874774151,7.521827058961892) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-7.471274548839627,4) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-7.2597599737546705,4.560623007772495) node {$E$};
\draw[color=black] (-8.951876574434324,5.512438595654801) node {$h$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-4.438909754691155,6.252615209824085) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-4.219237956908417,6.807965368050162) node {$F$};
\draw[color=black] (-5.620522016846255,5.115848767370507) node {$i$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-6.967268362401102,9.177116843795076) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-6.757412857927898,9.742730097353938) node {$G$};
\draw[color=black] (-8.132257595980116,8.050613496674284) node {$j$};
\draw[color=black] (-5.93779387947369,7.759780955932468) node {$k$};
\draw[color=black] (-6.968927433012855,5.062970123599269) node {$l$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-4.430752531993374,4) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-4.219237956908417,4.560623007772495) node {$H$};
\draw[color=black] (-4.774463716506428,5.433120629997942) node {$m$};
\draw[color=black] (-7.1804420080978115,6.490693505422727) node {$n$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As it stands, the drawing is about 40 centimeter wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code produced by GeoGebra should always be heavily edited.

In this case, the `axis` environment causes the picture to be about 40 centimeter wide and is quite likely unneeded.

I also edited the ridiculous accuracy and reformatted a bit for the font size.

The labels on the segments have been commented out as they're not useful for understanding the picture. The line width has also been reduced.

It just remains to fix the placement of the vertex labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49,0.49,1}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,1}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line cap=round,
  line join=round,
  x=1cm,y=1cm,
  font=\scriptsize,
]
\draw [
  shift={(-10,4)},
  line width=1pt
]  plot[domain=0:1.57,variable=\t]({1*6*cos(\t r)+0*6*sin(\t r)},{0*6*cos(\t r)+1*6*sin(\t r)});
\draw [line width=1pt] (-10,10)-- (-10,4);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-10,4)-- (-4,4);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-10,6.95)-- (-7.47,4);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-7.47,4)-- (-4.44,6.25);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-10,6.95)-- (-6.97,9.18);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-6.97,9.18)-- (-4.44,6.25);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-10,4)-- (-4.44,6.25);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-4.44,6.25)-- (-4.43,4);
\draw [line width=1pt] (-10,6.95)-- (-4.44,6.25);
\draw [fill=ududff] (-10,4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (-9.8,4.56) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=ududff] (-4,4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (-3.8,4.56) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=ududff] (-10,10) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (-9.8,10.40) node {$C$};
%\draw[color=black] (-5.51,8.71) node {$c$};
%\draw[color=black] (-10.33,7.31) node {$f$};
%\draw[color=black] (-6.92,3.9) node {$g$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-10,6.95) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-9.8,7.52) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-7.47,4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-7.26,4.56) node {$E$};
%\draw[color=black] (-8.95,5.51) node {$h$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-4.44,6.25) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-4.22,6.81) node {$F$};
%\draw[color=black] (-5.62,5.12) node {$i$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-6.97,9.18) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-6.76,9.74) node {$G$};
%\draw[color=black] (-8.13,8.05) node {$j$};
%\draw[color=black] (-5.94,7.76) node {$k$};
%\draw[color=black] (-6.97,5.06) node {$l$};
\draw [fill=xdxdff] (-4.43,4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (-4.22,4.56) node {$H$};
%\draw[color=black] (-4.77,5.43) node {$m$};
%\draw[color=black] (-7.18,6.49) node {$n$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very very much.. it is really great.... Thanks a lot once again.. God bless you always .....